# Lenovo W530 with Windows 8.1 not recognizing external monitor

Tags: thinkpad, vga, integrated-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card

I just got a Lenovo W530 through work running Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit.

My VGA port on the side of the laptop does not recognize any external monitor plugged into it. My company's IT guys and I have been fighting with it for week to no avail.

I have tried several drivers, from Intel's site and Lenovo's site.

It has Intel HD Graphics 4000 and NVIDIA Quadro K1000M for its display drivers. Not sure which one is the VGA one.

I've also tried changing the BIOS setting to NVIDIA Optimus, Discrete and Integrated graphics.

I tried moving my HDD into a different laptop and I had the same issues, so it doesn't seem to be a hardware issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.

This is the only solution that works for me:
Reinstall the latest NVIDIA driver, set the BIOS to use only Discrete graphics and disable Optimus.